# Why is the scalar velocity vector, or speed, $v(t)=|r'(t)|$ and not $v(t) = |r(t)|'$

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

The formula for finding the scalar quantity of the velocity vector is $v(t)=$|**v(t)**|=$|r'(t)|$ where $r(t)$ is the position function. On the surface this makes sense, since **v(t)**=$r'(t)$, meaning **v(t)** is describing the velocity and its length will be the scalar quantity of that velocity. However, if $|r(t)|$ describes the distance of an object from the origin, shouldn't $|r(t)|'$ then be how quickly this object is changing position, or in other words the speed?

Similarly, the textbook I'm using describes the scalar acceleration vector as $a(t)=$|**v(t)**|'. But then why isn't it $a(t)=$|**v(t)**'| like we defined for velocity?

Comment: The function $|r|$ may not be everywhere differentiable.

Comment: Note that $\mid r(t) \mid $ measures the distance from the origin, meaning that for example if we take a circular motion of radius $a$, then $\mid r(t)\mid =a$ is constant ($\mid r(t)\mid ' = 0$) but the object is changing position.

Comment: If, as you say, $\vert r\vert$ measures the distance of an object from the origin, then $\vert r\vert'$ measures how fast the distance from the origin changes. But that's not what velocity measures, since velocity measures *all* kinds of movement, not just movement away from or towards the origin.

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense. I still don't see why $a(t)=|v(t)|'$ instead of $a(t)=|v(t)'|$ though. It seems like it should be the latter, since given an acceleration vector $A(t)$ the $|A(t)|$ should be the scalar acceleration, but my textbook describes it as the former.

Comment: Are you sure your book defines the magnitude of acceleration as $a(t) = \lvert\mathbf v(t)\rvert'$? That definition would imply that an object in uniform circular motion in an inertial frame experiences no acceleration, which is false.

Comment: "The quantity $|v(t)|$ is the speed of the object; $|v(t)|'$ is the rate at which the speed is changing, or the scalar acceleration of the object, $a(t)$." Direct quote from the text :/ It's an opentext textbook, so its free. The name is Calculus Early Transcendentals by Guichard if you'd like to see for yourself.

Comment: I'd offer a snarky remark that you get what you pay for, but non-free textbooks sometimes have weird things in them too. The thing Guichard calls scalar acceleration I would call tangential acceleration: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Vector_Calculus/2%3A_Vector-Valued_Functions_and_Motion_in_Space/2.6%3A_Tangential_and_Normal_Components_of_Acceleration